# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted

Tags: android, flutter

i have a callback function in androidnative side when i call result.success multiple times app crashes, when i run app for first time able to get the expected outupt but and once again call the function app crashes in flutter side.

Android Function Code:

```
case MY_EVENTS:
                EVENT.trackUIEvents(new MyEventsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEventDone(MyEvent myEvent) {
                        if (myEvent != null) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                jsonObject.put("event_id", myEvent.eventID());
                                jsonObject.put("event_name", myEvent.eventName());
                                jsonObject.put("event_type", myEvent.eventType());
                                jsonObject.put("event_label", myEvent.eventLabel());
                              
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            result.success(jsonObject.toString());
                            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
                        } else {
                            result.error("0", "Could not fetch data", null);
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
```

Flutter Function code:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> trackUIEvents() async {
    final String jsonString = await _channel.invokeMethod(MY_EVENTS);
    Map<String, dynamic> result = <String, dynamic>{};

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      result = json.decode(jsonString);
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      List<dynamic> list = json.decode(jsonString);
      result = list[0];
    }
    return result;
  }
```

result.success() not executed on callback it runs only first time if i send callback to this app crashes, how to get updated result always means multiple times from result.success()

i have to invoke result.success() multiple times to get updated callback data .

Comment: Kindly share your tried code.

Comment: Try using stream instead of future return type on trackUIEvents method.

Comment: i changed to stream but error, remains same i have to invoke result.success() multiple times to get updated callback data

Answer (score -1):

You should define the *result* on top of the class where you check CASE MY_EVENTS instead of *trackUIEvents* method

```
 Map<String, dynamic> result = <String, dynamic>{};
```

Comment: it's doesn't mean that it's working on first time without any problem crashes in simultaneous callback